# Android 2.3 Hebrew fonts in Webview

Tags: android, webview, emulation

I am porting an app that displays Hebrew to Android 2.3. The 2.3 emulator displays the strings correctly when in a TextView, but when I try to put the strings in a WebView, the webview just displays gibberish.

This tells me that the Hebrew fonts are available in the emulator but the webview code has something missing.

This is the code:

```
     WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     mWebView.loadData("<html><body>"+temp1 +"</body></html>",
            "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Any ideas on how to get the emulator to display the webview correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please go through your previous questions and mark the best answer as the "correct" answer by clicking the checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: Please close this question, it has already been sufficiently answered below (complete with code snippets even).

Answer (score 2):

When you display the page, you aren't giving a way for the browser to know that your page uses a right-to-left script.

You can use the HTML `dir` attribute in a markup element that surrounds your right-to-left text (it should detect automatically which characters to reverse, and which not to). (For more details, look at [this note from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/#ri20030218.135307338) - it seems to be implemented in Chrome at least.)

Probably the most expedient way would be to rewrite the first tag as:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the font of the webview by adding

```
         mWebView.getSettings().setFixedFontFamily("DroidSansHebrew.ttf");
```

The text is rendered in the correct font but left-to-right which is not the correct orientation for Hebrew.