# Android 2.3 Hebrew Support in Webview

Tags: android, webview, hebrew, right-to-left

I have testing an app I ported to 2.3 on the Android 2.3 emulator, the app includes Hebrew strings displayed in a WebView required solving three problems:

1. Telling webview to use hebrew fonts (see my post with solution her [Android 2.3 Hebrew fonts in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392521/android-2-3-hebrew-fonts-in-webiew))
2. Telling webview to display the string right to left, which I solved by adding

   ```
           <p dir="rtl">
   ```
3. The last problem is that webview mirrors the text: in other words the first word that should be on the right is the last word on the left and also the letters of that word are flipped, the first letter that should be on the right is the first letter from the left.

BTW, the 2.3 emaulator displays the string correctly if in a TextView.

Any ideas on how to fix #3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using webview that needs to show a complete hebrew website.

I can tell you that I didn't encounter any problem you have listed, but I DO know that sometimes the os (especially when it's custom) doing some problems with hebrew.

If you want to check it more closely, just download the 3.X (Honeycomb) platform to the sdk manager, and try it again (Honeycomb should have built-in hebrew display, so there shouldn't be any problems. If you want, you can send me the link and il'l check it out.